# Matplotlib -- TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib

I am new into ML. As per video tutorials when i try to execute the following lines i get an error.
However the instructor get successful execution.
[image]

Error is :

### [image]

i have google about it but didnt get any clue. May be there is change in library ?
How can i solve this Error.

Comment: Can you add a link to the video tutorial you are referring to? Having all the code in correct format to copy and paste and not type as well as a sample of your data. Without knowing what X_train and y_train look like it's almost impossible to replicate your problem.

Comment: its a course on Udemy
`https://www.udemy.com/machinelearning/`

here is the code file link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w9ujZqlUaF-6lOwk_2GgBIDew8dAdRZ2

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```